# High Trust v/s Low Trust

Tags: high-trust-app

Can anyone explain to me what does High trust and low trust mean in SharePoint (or any other thing) in layman language? I am coming across these terms frequently in SharePoint but unable to understand. 
Also, are High trust and FUll trust different ?
If yes please explain the difference.

Comment: Guys ,Please help me by tagging appropriate tags. It would be greate help.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell,

Low trust --> uses access tokens from a provider (Azure for example).

High trust --> uses digital certificates to validate the endpoints.

This link is what helped me understand it (sort of):

http://www.instantquick.com/index.php/high-trust-apps-and-low-trust-apps-what-does-it-all-mean?c=elumenotion-blog-archive/sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-apps

Comment: Still I didnt get from article what I wanted to understand. Are farm solutions run on full trust. Or provider hosted app run on high trust. Or please provide me some example and impact of different scenerio.

Answer (score 0):

High-trust and Full-trust are different. Farm solutions yes running as Full-trust. High-trust apps use S2S authentication using digital certificates. Here is good link which explains the difference: https://www.sharepointeurope.com/high-trust-apps-in-sharepoint-2013/